# $\bar{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R} -A$ doesn't hold

Tags: general-topology

> Let ($\mathbb{R},T$) be the topological space as follows $A=\{\frac1n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and let $\mathcal B'= \{ B\in P(\mathbb{R})\mid  B \text{ is an open interval that doesn't contain $0$ or there is a positive number $x$} \text{ such that } B=(-x,x)-A\}$ Show that there is no neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ such that $\overline{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R} - A$.

Intuitively it is clear that this closure of $U$ must contain all points of $A$ except finitely many but I am unable to write a rigorious proof. I thought I should assume that there exists such a neighbourhood $U$ but I was unable to think how should I proceed to  find a contradiction.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** By construction, if $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$, then it contains $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\setminus A$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.
Let $n>\frac1{\epsilon}$ be arbitrary natural number and show that $\frac1n\in\overline U$.